# How can I get my module exported to the browser without using Module.default notation?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, lodash, umd

How can I make webpack expose my module to the browser directly to the Module name instead of using `Module.default`?

Here is my app setup in a simplified manner to hopefully portray what I am hoping to achieve.

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
        path: './lib',
        filename: 'app.js',
        library: 'App',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        umdNamedDefine: true
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader'
        }]
    }
};
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"],
    "plugins": ["babel-plugin-add-module-exports"]
}
```

**app.js**

```
export default function main() {
    console.log('The default function');
}

export function other() {
    console.log('A random function');
}
```

---

Because I specified "App" as the "library" in the output, my library is available in the browser as `App`.

The weird thing is... in order to use the default function that was exported I have to do `App.default`. But to use the `other` exported function I can do this: `App.other`. I would expect that I could do `App()` to call the default exported function, and the other would be the same `App.other()`.

Is this standard behavior in the browser or a UMD wrapped library with webpack? This does not seem to mimic the behavior of the lodash library. Is my configuration off in some way?

---

However, if you take a look at the [lodash library (repo)](https://github.com/lodash/lodash) in the browser, you can see that they acheived it.

Lodash is built using webpack. If you take a look inside of the package.json for lodash, you can see that the main file is `lodash.js`. If you take a look at that file, it appears to be UMD wrapped (UMD definition at the bottom of the file). Therefore, when I do things like:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
// or
import {clamp} from 'lodash';
```

everything works fine.

The other thing that works fine is referencing that exact file in an HTML file:

```
<script src="node_modules/lodash/lodash.js"></script>
```

Which allows me access to the lodash object.

```
console.log(_) // function
console.log(_.clamp) // function clamp(number, lower, upper) { ... }
```

How can I get the same behavior. Lodash's webpack config is much more complicated than I need, and am not sure what I need to reverse engineer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `libraryExport: 'default'` to the output configuration of webpack;
also you don't need `babel-plugin-add-module-exports`.

Comment: Yeah, this was a nice change with the newer versions of webpack.